# Android - StringDef dont warn using a getter and equals

Tags: android, android-support-library

I want to use `StringDef` to avoid enums... that´s the idea right?

So I have a day variable and I want to compare it but show a warning if is not a valid day... using @Day...

I´m trying:

```
public static final String SUNDAY = "a";
public static final String MONDAY = "b";

@StringDef(value = {
    SUNDAY,
    MONDAY
})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface Day {
}

@Day
public String getDay(){
    ...
}

object.getDay().equals("Any String")   -> SHOULD SHOW WARNING 
object.getDay().equals(Object.MONDAY)   -> NO WARNING
```

Why?

[Support Annotation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/support-annotations)

Comment: How are you testing this? Are you manually running Lint? I think Android Studio 1.4 will check for these via in-IDE inspections, but I'm not sure if 1.3 supports that, meaning the complaints might only come about if you run Lint. Once upon a time, Lint was run all the time, but it got too slow, so right now Lint is a manual thing.

Comment: I´m using 1.4 beta 4, the warning just appear when I use `==` but not with .equals(), but strings should be compared with equals...

Comment: Hmmm... it's possible this is a bug. `@IntDef` and `@ColorInt` would compare via `==`. FWIW, plenty of Android and Java experts ([Jake Wharton](https://twitter.com/JakeWharton/status/638447874515275776), [Bob Lee](https://twitter.com/crazybob/status/636959556539539457), and [Joshua Bloch](https://twitter.com/joshbloch/status/628663950389841920), to name three) are opposed to the "enums are teh evilz" argument. So the simpler answer may be to just use the enum.

Comment: Hmmmmmmmmm, I ended up creating a method: `boolean isDay(@Day String day) { return this.day.equals(day)}` and it will check that, but is not a good idea?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186598&thanks=186598&ts=1442443687 reported here.